# Have to make all existing GUIDs in a database unique again. Is there a mathematical operation to do this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid

We have a database which was at one point a copy of our current Production DB. Therefore some GUIDs are not unique between databases. We are now using a provider which does not have a sandbox for preproduction/testing, so the two databases access the provider data, causing collisions.

Is there a mathematical operation to apply to all guids in the non-production database to transform them determinately? Unfortunately there are some instances of non-keyed associations, so cascading updates will not do.

Comment: Create a mapping table with columns old_guid, new_guid and use newid() to generate new GUIDs then update using the mapping table

Comment: My suggestion is to unload the smaller table, create all new GUID's, change all the GUID's. and then load the table.

Comment: If `NEWSEQUENTIALID` was never used, adding 1 to a certain byte of the guids would prob work. Not what I would do (I would do like Martin Smith), but a necessary bodge is a necessary bodge